# Displaying an image after pressing submit html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to display an image after i press submit

```
<img id="image1" src="images/Coverflow1.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="$('#image1').show()"/>
```

Name is retrieved by

```
var y=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
```

Where fname is

```
<h4>Name: <input type="text" name="fname" size="61" /></h4>
```

Only problem is this is using Jquery, so I can't seem to pass it through any of my other 
validations like checking if the name field is null.

```
if (name==null || name=="")
    {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
    }
```

Is there a Javascript equivalent to this that I can stick in my else statement so it will only show it if the form actually submits properly passing the validation checks beforehand?

Thanks

Comment: A form first name field where people enter their first name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do all that in jquery.

```
if (name==null || name=="")
{
alert("First name must be filled out");
return false;
}
else
{
$('#image1').show()
}
```

Comment: What happens if they submit the form via the enter button? `onclick` won't fire in that case.

Comment: My form doesn't even submit with enter, problem solved... haha, i'm just getting the hang of things at the moment, this isn't for anything major

Comment: It will if an element in the form has focus. I take it you don't have any elements in the form at the moment. Learning to do things the wrong way isn't efficient learning, @Jim.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `.submit()` event handler of jQuery instead of attaching an `onclick` property to the submit button. The `onclick` property will not fire its function in the event that a user submits the form via the enter key; however, the `.submit()` method will capture it as well.

```
$("form[name=myForm]").submit(function(e) {
  //get value of name here.
  var name = this.fname.value; //this refers to the form, because that is what is being submitted.

  //Do validation.
  if (name == null || name == "") {
      //If failed, then prevent the form from submitting.
      alert("First name must be filled out.");
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
  }

  //If validation passed, show image.
  $("#image1").show();

});
```

Comment: Yeah cheers, that's good advice, i was just doing some simple for now, thanks though, i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `onclick` attribute from the submit button:

```
<img id="image1" src="images/Coverflow1.jpg" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Since you're using jQuery, attaching handlers to click events in JavaScript is a snap (and it's also a good practice).

I almost always use the following pattern for form validation (and on the `submit` of the `form`, rather than the `click` of the `submit` button because there are other ways to submit forms than clicking the button).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formIsValid = function formIsValid () {
        // your validation routines go here
        // return a single boolean for pass/fail validations
        var name =document.forms.myForm.fname.value;
        return !!name; // will convert falsy values (like null and '') to false and truthy values (like 'fred') to true.
    };
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var allGood = formIsValid();
        if (!allGood) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $('#image1').toggle(allGood); // hide if validation failed, show if passed.
        return allGood; // stops propagation and prevents form submission if false.
    });
});
```